# Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1) When using sudo apt install --fix-broken

Tags: linux, ubuntu-20.04

when trying to remove nodjs from my Ubuntu `sudo apt-get remove nodejs`
Getting error `E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).`
When performing `sudo apt install --fix-broken` iam getting below error.

Any reason why iam getting this issue.

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree        
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
linux-image-5.11.0-46-generic 
Suggested packages:
fdutils linux-doc | linux-hwe-5.11-source-5.11.0 linux-hwe-5.11-tools
The following NEW packages will be installed:
linux-image-5.11.0-46-generic
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 132 not upgraded.
4 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/11.5 MB of archives.
After this operation, 11.8 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 208109 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../linux-image-5.11.0-46-generic_5.11.0-46.51~20.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-image-5.11.0-46-generic (5.11.0-46.51~20.04.1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-5.11.0-46- 
generic_5.11.0-46.51~20.04.1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
unable to open '/boot/vmlinuz-5.11.0-46-generic.dpkg-new': Operation not permitted
Errors were encountered while processing:
/var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-5.11.0-46-generic_5.11.0-46.51~20.04.1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try it:

```sh
apt clean
apt autoclean

cd /var/lib/dpkg/
mv info/ info_bak
mkdir info
apt-get update
apt-get -f install
mv info/* info_bak/
rm -rf info
mv info_bak info
```

I think this will solve your problem, execute all commands in order.

Comment: When iam firing `apt-get -f install` still getting the error . `Unpacking linux-image-5.11.0-46-generic (5.11.0-46.51~20.04.1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-5.11.0-46-generic_5.11.0-46.51~20.04.1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 unable to open '/boot/vmlinuz-5.11.0-46-generic.dpkg-new': Operation not permitted
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-5.11.0-46-generic_5.11.0-46.51~20.04.1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)`